# How to prevent Odoo scheduler from timing out?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am having some issues with the Odoo scheduler. I am running Odoo 13.

```
actions = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'ir.cron', 'search', [[['name', '=', 'Procurement: run scheduler']]])
print(actions)

schedule = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'ir.cron', 'method_direct_trigger', [actions])
print(schedule )
```

I have attempted to change my config multiple times, increasing the time-outs. But the issue still keeps happening.

The error is

```
xmlrpc.client.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for ip.adress/xmlrpc/2/object: 504 Gateway Time-out>
```

Comment: So you use the web API to trigger them? Maybe your proxy is timing out and not Odoo?

Comment: I am using the API just to debug. How would I go about checking the proxy vs odoo? Thank you

Comment: depends on your setup, and nobody but you know your setup ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the answer anywhere else. So for anyone else looking for a solution I had already made the proper configurations to the Odoo config file but I had to make the configs to the Nginx file as well.

I added the following under my `/location` in the server blocks

```
 proxy_read_timeout 1000s;
   proxy_connect_timeout 1000s;
   proxy_send_timeout 1000s;
```